# obtaining the data of a rectangle selection in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to understand the use of the RectangleSelector in matplotlib. Basically I'm plotting a 2D  array with imshow and then I would like to select a rectangle portion with the mouse and save the corner of the rectangle to be used later in the script. I read the RectangleSelector use in matplotlib documentation but I'm not able to obtain the data.
What I have done for now is the following

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import bumpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
# let z be my 2D array
z=np.ones((100,1000))
def onselect(eclick, erelease):
  'eclick and erelease are matplotlib events at press and release'
   print ' startposition : (%f, %f)' % (eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata)
   print ' endposition   : (%f, %f)' % (erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata)
   print ' used button   : ', eclick.button

fig=mpl.pylab.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(z,aspect='auto',origin='lower',extent=((0,100,0,1000)))
toggle_selector.RS=RectangleSelector(ax,onselect,drawtype='box',useblit=True,button=[1,3])
```

Now with the function onselect I print out the values of the (x,y) coordinate of the minimum and maximum of the rectangle. But I would like to store these values to be used later.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I just made a couple of global variables and stored the values of eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata, erelease.xdata and erelease.ydata in the global variables.

```
def onselect(eclick, erelease):
    global index
    global startpos
    global endpos
    print ' startposition : (%f, %f)' % (eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata)
    print ' endposition   : (%f, %f)' % (erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata)
    print ' used button   : ', eclick.button
    startpos[index] = [eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata]
    endpos[index]   = [erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata]
```

Not sure if it's the "best" way, but it worked :)

Comment: How to store the values (from the onselect() function) for later use.

Answer (score 1):

If you read through the documentation, you will find out that the returned object has properties like extents , geometry which contains all the information about the selection. I am 3 years late, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To add specifics to the answer from Navdeep...

```
rect_selection_coords = toggle_selector.RS.extents
print(rect_selection_coords)
x1, x2, y1, y2 = rect_selection_coords
```

Other attributes can be found in the [source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/37978a8a701530acc824500c7d4a09cad1d93d7c/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py) at github/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py line 2296.